# knockout "X is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a knockout model and am getting an error that I do not understand.

Here is the offending section of code:

```
<!-- ko with: SearchModel -->
...
            <img class="search-img" data-bind="visible: searching" src="@Url.Content("~/Static/Hypercube_Large_Light_Transparent.gif")" height="30" />
            <img id="searchIcon" class="search-img" data-bind="visible: !searching()" src="@Url.Content("~/Static/search_icon.png")" height="30" />
...
<!-- /ko -->
```

In SearchModel.js:

```
...
this.searching = ko.observable(false);
...
```

I get an error on the SECOND reference to `searching`.  The first one resolves just fine, and there are no other errors.  Weird thing, the code actually WORKS, so whenever I change the `searching` variable to `true`, the second image goes away and the first one appears, then when I change it back to `false`, the first goes away and the second appears.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: visible: !searching()
Message: searching is not defined
```

Comment: I don't see a reason for this, but I suspect the `with` is involved. Try `visible: !$data.searching()` or `visible:!$data.SearchModel.searching()`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to check for the existence of `SearchModel` prior to the `with` binding.

Something like:

`<!-- ko if: SearchModel() -->`

Or more specific:

`<!-- ko if: SearchModel() !== 'undefined' && SearchModel() !== null -->`

You could also, depending on your view model hierarchy, create a `ko.pureComputed` to check the existence of the `SearchModel` and in the HTML use code like:

`<!-- ko if: SomePureComputed -->`

Comment: The `with` binding doesn't throw an error, though.  And the first `searching` reference resolves, so it must know what `SearchModel` is.  How could it find the first `searching` and not the second?

Comment: A quick test using the method referenced in the KO documentation, is to dump the model to the DOM as JSON using the builtin toJSON method. The code: `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(SearchModel, null, 2)"></pre>`

Comment: When I put that above the `with` statement, I get `{
...
  "searching": false,
...
}`

Comment: @Scott if you temporarily remove the with binding and access the observable directly, do you still get the error?

Comment: I removed the `with` statement and replaced `searching` with `SearchModel().searching()` and `!searching()` with `!SearchModel().searching()`.  The first reference still works.  The second reference still fails, but now with "`SearchModel` is not defined"

Comment: No change in functionality

Comment: @Scott Unless you have an outer with binding, which I'd also like you to remove, the `SearchModel` approach won't work. Access directly using `$data.searching` and `!$data.searching()` respectively.

Comment: My models are nested rather deeply.  However, moving one more `with` layer up to have `ParentModel().SearchModel().searching()` and `!ParentModel().SearchModel().searching()` avoids the error.  Functionality is still the same, i.e. working properly.

Comment: @Scott Interesting approach. I can honestly say in my 5 years of extensive knockout usage, I've never used them.

Comment: I have a single page app, and there's a lot going on, so instead of trying to have everything in one model, there are separate models, and models within models.  Specifically, the search functionality comes back with results that are rather complex entities in their own right, so they are a nested model.  It works great, actually.  Even this was working fine, I just hate having red pop up in my dev console.  =c)

Comment: You should definitely checkout Components.